# Shortcut for determining equivalence relations?

Tags: relations

Is there a short cut to determine the number of equivalence relations on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$? I mean I could do that manually but for a larger set it becomes annoying. Is there a general way to partition it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, check [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

It gives you a [Recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) for calculating number of equivalence relations on a set having $n$ elements.

Comment: Yes thx. It is strange somehow. Using the Bell numbers I get for $n=4$ set $15$ different partitions...according to my solution there must be 18.

Comment: @mamba can u list the partitions u made, i'll try to correct u